# Customise Folder in Windows 10 Not Working

Tags: windows-explorer

I recently noticed that my customise folder options are not working anymore and i have to manually change the columns of each folder instead of applying the settings to the folders i want via the customise tab.

For example instead of size, date modified etc i want to make folders for music but nothing changes when i apply via the customise tab so i have to go into the folder and manually select contributing artist, album, title etc

Worse yet this also resets so in my music folder it defaults back to date modified, size etc when i want the columns for music, very annoying especially when you have loads of folders full of music

This is with

- Windows 10 Pro, Version: 1903, Build: 18362.239
- PC has i7 6700k, M.2, 16 GB Ram. GTX 1080

Please check pictures for examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was solved on another forum but for anyone having the same issue I was told to simply reset folder view settings in windows (google how to) and it totally worked, I am now able to change and keep columns and apply to sub-folders like before, I think the latest windows update borked something but all seems fine now, many thanks.